# Eloquent метод save не работает

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

На удаленном сервере не работает метод `save`. Методом дебага, обнаружил, что в модели не создается идентификатор. Код:

```
$company = new Company();
$company->user_id = $request->user_id;
$company->name = $request->name;
if (isset($request->logo)) {
    $company->logo = $request->logo;
}
$company->email = $request->email;
$company->site = $request->website;
$company->number = $number;
$company->description = $request->description;
$company->save();
$id = $company->id;
```

Так вот, если задать `$company->id = 111`, к примеру, модель сохраняется.
Никто не сталкивался с таким явлением?

Answer (score 1):

Покажите код самой модели и ее миграцию, возможно проблема в миграции, например не указано в схеме

```
$table->increments("id");
```

какой результат если для создания обьекта используете конструктор?

```
Company::create([
  'user_id' => $request->user_id,
  'name' => $request->name,
  'logo' => isset($request->logo) ? $request->logo : '',
  ...
]);
```